# Php: sessions are not working?

Tags: php

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['btnLogin']))

        {

             $id = $_POST['email'];

             $pass = $_POST['password'];

         // Resource Address

            $url ="http://localhost:81/RouteApp/ViewApi/?id=$id&pass=$pass";

         // Send Request To Resource

            $client = curl_init($url);

            curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

         // get Response To Resource

            $response = curl_exec($client);


         // Decode it

            $result = json_decode($response);
            session_start();
             $res  =   (array)$result->data;
             foreach ($res as $key) {
                 $_SESSION['sessId']=$key[0];
                 $_SESSION['sessName']=$key[1];
                 $_SESSION['sessEmail']=$key[2];
             }

           header("Location:index.php");
        }
?>
```

Comment: Please state your current situation and question clearly.

Comment: i had problem in setting php session . in the above code value stored in session variable but when it redirect to index.php. user login session not set

Comment: Basically iam using Rest API and after Json Decode i have setting my Session Variables.

Comment: i had made Login Rest API but now i need to make sessions?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the above details. Code-only question are subject to closing at any time.

Comment: Your `foreach` loop doesn't make any sense! Your session data will always be the data from the last item in `$res`!

Comment: Do you have any solution to this problem?

Comment: just tell me how to set user login session using Rest API plz any one?

Comment: You're really not stating _any_ problem; if you mean the `foreach` issue, then I just suggest that if your `$res` variable is just a simple one dimension array then you may remove the loop and use it: `$_SESSION['sessId'] = $res[0];`

Comment: If you can't access the session data in the `index.php`, you may have not resumed the session variable using the `session_start()` there! (As I've stated in my answer below, call `session_start()` before using sessions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you use session, you need to start or resume the session using `session_start()` function.

Comment: i had did this but still itis not working

Comment: @SaqibMurtaza *What* is not working?!

Comment: i had resume the session but still it is not working

Comment: <?php
                               if(isset($_SESSION['sessId']))
                                {
                             ?>
                             <li>
    
                 <a href="" class="icon fa-angle-down"> <?php echo $_SESSION['sessName']; ?> </a>    <ul>
  <li><a href="#"><?php echo $_SESSION['sessEmail']; ?></a></li><li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li> </ul></li><?php
  }   if(!isset($_SESSION['sessId'])             {  
               ?>
                           <li><a href="login.php" class="button1">Log In</a></li>      <?php
                } 
           ?>

Comment: this is my index file

Comment: There is **no** `session_start()` anywhere in your index file!! Please notice that as I've stated multiple times, to use session, you need to start or resume session using `session_start()`. **Add** `session_start()` to the beginning of your index file :)

Comment: Thanks now it's in working condition